# Как разумно сочетать статический и динамический полиморфизм?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, интерфейс, полиморфизм, итераторы

При реализации интерфейса итератора для обобщенного типа данных, я столкнулся со  следующей рекомендацией:
 *"... не помещайте виртуальные функции в шаблон класса, если только вы не хотите, чтобы каждый раз инстанцировались все виртуальные функции (в противоположность невиртуальным функциям шаблонных типов)"*
 [Стандарты программирования на C++, рекомендация №64 (Саттер, Алесандреску)
http://programming-lang.com/ru/comp_programming/satter/0/j133.html ]

Из этих соображений я переделал свой старый код:

```
template<class Item>
class IIterator {
public:
    virtual ~IIterator();
    virtual void First() = 0;
    virtual void Next() = 0;
    virtual bool IsDone() const = 0;
    virtual Item * CurrentItem() const = 0;
protected:
    IIterator();
}
//...
template<class T>
class IteratorList: public IIterator<T> { ... }
```

следующим образом:

```
class IIterator {
public:
    virtual ~IIterator();
    virtual void First() = 0;
    virtual void Next() = 0;
    virtual bool IsDone() const = 0;
    template<class Item>
    Item * CurrentItem() const  {
        return nullptr;
    }
protected:
    IIterator();
};
//...
template<class T>
class IteratorList: public IIterator { ... }
```

Как я понял, моя вторая редакция интерфейса итератора позволит:

1. - раздельно компилировать модули, наследующие этот интерфейс
2. - избегнуть *чрезмерного ограничения* моего обобщенного типа

Правильно ли я понял и применил вышеуказанную рекомендацию?

---

Интересно, а если реализовать CurrentItem следующим образом:

```
template<class Item>
Item* IIterator::CurrentItem() {
assert(!"Incorrectly overridden");
return nullptr;
}
```

то как мне кажется и шаблонный:

```
template<class Item>
Item * CurrentItem() const;
```

и виртуальный:

```
virtual Item * CurrentItem() const = 0;
```

варианты `CurrentItem` будит одинаково выполнять свой контракт? Ну естественно за тем исключением, что предупреждение в шаблонном варианте сможет возникнуть лишь на этапе выполнения.

Comment: Во втором варианте, функция CurrentItem не виртуальныя, поэтому переопределить ее в наследнике невозможно. Т.е. она всегда возвращает NULL. Мне сложно представить алгоритм, в котором нужно оперировать итераторами, но ненужно иметь доступа к значениям, на которые они указывают.  Если же алгоритм должен получит доступ к значению, то он в любом случае должен знать его тип, и второй вариант не будет иметь преимуществ перед первым.

Comment: да, но  это не есть разумное сочетание - абсолютно ненужная функция у вас CurrentItem ...

Comment: хотел получит уточнеие в комментарие, но не справиля с формотированием, решил дополнить вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь ваша проблема в том, что вы не можете переопределить `CurrentItem`. В книге GOF итератор был реализован на базе того, что был известен тип объектов. В вашем случае это было-бы примерно так:

```
class IItem{
public:
    //интерфейс
    virtual ~IItem(){}
};

class IIterator{
public:
    virtual IItem* CurrentItem() const = 0;
    //...
};
```

Но такое решение не применимо, если у хранимых объектов нет общего интерфейса. В этом случае вам как-ни крути придется создавать для каждого типа свой итератор. Я вижу следующие пути:

---

**Не думать об этом.** Во всяком случае до тех пор пока это не стало узким местом. Есть такое мнение, что код нужно писать так чтобы он был в первую очередь читаемым и сопровождаемым. Любые оптимизации усложняют и запутывают код. Ваша первая версия вполне понятная и простая.

---

**Доверить контроль типов пользователю.** А именно протащить всё через `void*`.

```
virtual void* CurrentItem() const = 0;
```

Очень сомнительное решение. Похожая история была с коллекциями в Java, до появления дженериков(кастрированные шаблоны). Очень благоприятная почва для ошибок.

---

**Использовать только статический полиморфизм.** Так сделано в STL, вроде неплохо получилось. Только в этом случае все пользователи вашего итератора станут тоже шаблонными. И для того, чтобы явно указать требуемый интерфейс, придется извращаться с CRTP или ждать концепты(если честно, не знаю когда их подвезут).

---

Итог. Рекомендация называется *"Разумно сочетайте статический и динамический полиморфизм"*. На мой взгляд самым разумным решением будет оставить как есть. Остальные ухищрения только усложнят и запутают код.

Comment: > _На мой взгляд самым разумным решением будет оставить как есть_
Да, согласен с вам, канонический варан итератора не самый лучший пример для применения выше указанной рекомендации Саттера и Александреску. Интересно бы увидеть где эта рекомендация действительно помогает улучшить код. Примеры к которым отсылает сама книжка показались мне очень сложными, я мало что там понял :)